# Java - Will changes to class variables in recursive functions be deleted afterwards?

Tags: recursion, minimax

I'm trying to implement minimax algorithm.

*(**For those who aren't familiar**: a recursive function for 2 opponents (each has its own turn. ex. chess,go etc), which calculates what is the best move for each turn of a player, by calculating recursively the outcome of a selected move for player A and vice versa.*

*It is called Minimax because the first player always tries to maximize his outcome, while the second always tries to minimize first's outcome [Which also means maximizing his])**.***

The player's class that invokes the function has the board (which is another class). 
The player plays by placing a piece in its board, and there's another function to calculate the score/heuristic score whatever.

My question is the following: When calculating each player's outcome, I need to actually place the piece on the board, then do all calculations. Will my changes be deleted once I go up the recursive tree again?

I sense it won't, because even that Java passes by value, I still alter Player's table. so I wonder if I should duplicate my current board every time and play virtually / pass a board as an argument/ and so on...

Comment: In principle - no, they will not. A change is a change, there is no notion of "rollback" in Java, because there is no notion of "previous" value. However, to make matters clearer, please show some example code.

Comment: I didn't put any code on purpose.. And you pointed it very clearly. I try to understand how to solve my question in general. Simply - when trying to calculate results based on class attributes and variables, is there a general way to create this "rollback" behavior (Instead of creating a new "class" every time)?

Comment: You must mean "new instance", not "new class". It's still not clear as to what is the change we're talking here. In certain cases, since this is recursive function, rollback is simply the operation in reverse, which doesn't need extra object, but needs extra CPU. Otherwise you do need some kind of operations log, be it a stack of dedicated objects, or new instances of operating class on each call.

Answer (score 0):

> I sense it won't, because even that Java passes by value, I still alter Player's table. so I wonder if I should duplicate my current board every time and play virtually / pass a board as an argument/ and so on...

That is one option. Another solution (often more efficient computationally) is to implement and use an `undo()` function that reverses the effect of a move on the board.